# How can I specify non-deducible template parameters on a constructor?

Tags: c++, templates

It's possible to give a templated constructor template parameters that cannot be deduced:

```
struct X
{
    int i;

    template<int N>
    X() : i(N)
    {
    }
};
```

How would you use such a constructor? Can you use it at all?

Comment: You can't. Since constructors don't have names, you can't specify template arguments of constructor templates. All template arguments must be deducible.

Comment: You can of course achieve compile-time constant expression initialization by other means, e.g. tag dispatch with a `std::integral_constant` parameter etc.

Comment: What is your use case?

Comment: @DieterLücking, I would have used it with a type to wrap the allocation of an object. I'm using a function instead, similar to `make_unique`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you [**can't specify constructor template arguments**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2861839/819272). There are a few alternatives.

1. As indicated in the comments by @KerrekSB, you can give the constructor template a `std::integral_constant` parameter, which when passed as an argument, will deduce `N`:

Code:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <type_traits>

struct X
{
    int i;

    template<int N>
    X(std::integral_constant<int, N>) : i(N)
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::integral_constant<int, 6> six;
    X x(six);
    assert(x.i == 6);
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a445ba46a282d9bf)

2. You can write a dedicated `make_X<N>` template wrapper that hides the `integral_constant` boiler-plate:

Code:

```
template<int N>
X make_X()
{
    return X(std::integral_constant<int, N>{});        
}

int main()
{
    auto y = make_X<42>();
    assert(y.i == 42);
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d30daad3552c1800)