# constructor with variadic template arguments of the same type does not compile

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, template-argument-deduction

I am trying to construct a class having using  variadic template constructor.
The template arguments are all the same type.

I am using Visual C++ compiler with C++ 17, but code does not build; this code is actually crashing the compiler.

Is that possible in C++17 ?

```
 struct Alfa {
     template<int... T>
     Alfa(const T&... all_args) {
         std::tuple<T...> data(all_args...);       
     }    
 };

 Alfa alfa(1,2,3,4);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The template arguments are all the same type. [...] is that possible in C++17 ?

Yes, it's possible.

But non in a so simple way and with some drawbacks.

You can write a constructor accepting arguments of different type; this is simple

```
 template <typename ... Ts>
 Alfa (const Ts & ... as) 
  { std::tuple<Ts...> data{as...}; }
```

but this permit that the `Ts...` types are different.

You can impose that all types are the same, using SFINAE, as follows

```
 template <typename T, typename ... Ts,
           std::enable_if_t<(std::is_same_v<T, Ts> && ...), bool> = true>
 Alfa (T const & a0, Ts const & ... as)
  {
     std::tuple<T, Ts...> data0{a0, as...};       
     std::array           data1{a0, as...};
  }
```

so your constructor is enabled only if all `Ts...` types, following the first `T`, are exactly the same as `T`

Drawback: works with

```
   Alfa alfa{1, 2, 3, 4};
```

but gives an error with

```
   Alfa alfa{1l, 2l, 3, 4l};  <-- 3 isn't long
```

because `3` is convertible to `long` (`1l` is `long`) but isn't `long`.

So you can check if the following `Ts...` are convertible to `T`, instead if they are equals

```
 template <typename T, typename ... Ts,
           std::enable_if_t<(std::is_convertible_v<Ts, T> && ...), bool> = true>
 Alfa (T const & a0, Ts const & ... as)
  {
     std::tuple<T, Ts...>             data0{a0, as...};       
     std::array<T, sizeof...(Ts)+1u>  data1{a0, as...};
  }
```

but this way you give to `T` a bigger importance to other types (works if all `Ts...` are convertible to `T` but not if `T` is convertible to one of the `Ts...`) so I suppose that the better solution is check if there is a common type

```
 template <typename ... Ts,
           typename CT = std::common_type_t<Ts...>>
 Alfa (Ts const & ... as)
  {
     std::tuple<Ts...>              data0{as...};       
     std::array<CT, sizeof...(Ts)>  data1{as...};
  }
```

Comment: You could simplify your final example using `std::common_type_t` like this `template<typename... Ts, typename = std::common_type_t<Ts...>>`

Comment: @Kerndog73 - yes, is exactly what I'm writing

Comment: Wow! I didn't think that it was not so straightforward. I was not even aware of std::common_type_t and that it could be used in such way. Thanks a lot for both comments. That solved my issue  perfectly.

Comment: @AbruzzoForteeGentile - answer improved for `std::common_type`

Comment: Yeas, I saw both your response and Max Langhof before. It's  very modern indeed and more compact. It's been there since C++11 but only today I found out about it. Thanks to both.

Answer (score 1):

You have to decide whether you want non-type template arguments or not. Your code first says "the `T` are integer values", but then tries to use the `T` like a type in the function signature and `tuple` template argument list.

Valid options would be:

```
 struct Alfa {
     template<class ... Ts>
     Alfa(const Ts&... all_args) {
         std::tuple<Ts...> data(all_args...);       
     }    
 };

 Alfa alfa(1,2,3,4);
```

This doesn't encode the constraint of "all `Ts` have to be the same". There's no direct way to do that. You could use `static_assert` or SFINAE (see the other answer).

```
 template<int... Is>
 struct Alfa {
     Alfa() {
         std::tuple data(Is...); // Using class template argument deduction.
     }    
 };

 Alfa<1,2,3,4> alfa{};
```

This templates the class, not the constructor, which is most likely not what you want. It shows the syntax for accepting compile-time integer values (i.e. a non-type template parameter pack). But you cannot use deduction for non-type template parameters, so they have to be specified explicitly. But that's [impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861839/can-the-template-parameters-of-a-constructor-be-explicitly-specified) for the constructor!

A compromise might be:

```
 struct Alfa {
     template<class ... Ts>
     Alfa(const Ts&... all_args) {
         std::tuple<Ts...> data(all_args...);       
     }    
 };

 template<int ... Is>
 auto makeAlfa() { return Alfa(Is...); }

 Alfa alfa = makeAlfa<1,2,3,4>();
```

Comment: That's true. When I coded using template parameter T I did try lots of trial and error to make my example work. I like the suggestion about 'static_assert' which comes very handy and I find it stylish as well. Thanks  a lot for your response which solves as well my issue.