# How to pass template arguments via constructor?

Tags: c++, class, templates, constructor

I'm looking for a way to pass the template arguments of a template-based class (the main class of the [FastLED library on Arduino](http://fastled.io/docs/3.1/class_c_fast_l_e_d.html), to be specific) via the constructor of my own class (which should basically wrap the FastLED library). I want to specify the template arguments necessary to initialize FastLED in the main function, so that all pre-configuration before compiling (i.e. the `#define`s in the third code block below) works via constants in the main file. How can I achieve this?

Currently, my class looks like this:

LEDState.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "FastLED.h"
FASTLED_USING_NAMESPACE

class LEDState {
  private:
    CRGB* _leds;
    CRGB* _pixels;
    const uint16_t _pixel_count;
    const uint16_t _led_count;
    const uint8_t _mapmode;

  public:
    LEDState(const uint16_t pixel_count, const uint8_t mapmode);
    void show();
};
```

LEDState.cpp:

```
#include "LEDState.h"

LEDState::LEDState(const uint16_t pixel_count, const uint8_t mapmode)
: _pixel_count(pixel_count), _mapmode(mapmode), _led_count(_pixel_count * (_mapmode & 0x0f))
{
  _leds = (CRGB*)malloc(_led_count * sizeof(CRGB));
  _pixels = (CRGB*)malloc(_pixel_count * sizeof(CRGB));
  FastLED.addLeds<CHIPSET, DATA_PIN, CLOCK_PIN, COLOR_ORDER>(_leds, _led_count);
}

void LEDState::show() {
  for( int p = 0; p < _pixel_count; p++ ) {
    _leds[p] = _pixels[p];
  }
  FastLED.show();
}
```

My problem is that I did not find a way to pass the template arguments `<CHIPSET, DATA_PIN, CLOCK_PIN, COLOR_ORDER>` via the constructor of `LEDState`.

Is there a way to initialize my wrapper class *and* the wrapped FastLED library from my main file? I'm imagining my `main.ino` file like this:

```
#include "LEDState.h"

#define CHIPSET APA102
#define DATA_PIN 23
#define CLOCK_PIN 18
#define COLOR_ORDER GRB 

LEDState state = LEDState<CHIPSET, DATA_PIN, CLOCK_PIN, COLOR_ORDER>(led_count, map_mode);

void setup() {
}

void loop() {
  LEDState.show();
}
```

(with `APA102` and `GRB` being constants from the FastLED library.)

Is something like this possible at all?

(I'm not confident that I know the right vocabulary to search for a solution, leave alone using the right terminology in this question. Everything I found either wasn't a solution to my problem or I didn't understand that it was a solution. I'm coming from "plain Arduino C"; and my knowledge about C++ templates is roughly at: I can work my way through patching existing template code, but I don't know how to create a template.)

EDIT: With the comments and first answers, I guess that I need my class to also be templated. I tried copying the template argument list from the FastLED library (see link above), resulting in this class definition:

```
template<ESPIChipsets CHIPSET, uint8_t DATA_PIN, uint8_t CLOCK_PIN, EOrder COLOR_ORDER>
class LEDState {
  ...
}
```

(`ESPIChipsets` and `EOrder` are defined by FastLED)

Now the compiler complains with

```
LEDState.cpp:3:1: error: invalid use of template-name 'LEDState' without an argument list
 LEDState::LEDState(const uint16_t pixel_count, const uint8_t mapmode)
 ^
```

What else do I need to make it compile?

Comment: I don't follow.. If you need `LEDState` to be a template, what's stopping you from making it a template?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Because I don't know that it would need to be a template-based class itself. If that is indeed the case, my question would be "what do I need to know to turn my class into a template?"

Comment: @orithena `I don't know that it would need to be a template-based class itself` we don't know that either because it is not clear if that is important for you, also `so that all pre-configuration before compiling works` is not clear. And we don't know where you get `CHIPSET`, `DATA_PIN`, `CLOCK_PIN`, `COLOR_ORDER` from.

Comment: It would help if you show a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @t.niese I don't know whether me trying to pass-through the template arguments necessitates my class to also be a template class. As to the other points, I tried to clarify the question. (Still hindered by the fact that I'm not sure about the right terminology here.)

Comment: @AndreasDM I'd say this pretty much is an MRE, except I don't know a way to make it compile.

Comment: I suspect you just need your `LEDState` constructor to be templated.  That way you can simply pass the template params through to the `FastLED.addLeds` call.

Comment: @G.M. I tried that now with my limited knowledge about templates, but I'm running into follow-up errors. I guess my question is now "What's the minimal template decoration on my class to just pass-through the template arguments to the FastLED template?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you look into the FastLED implementation, it is written exactly how you want to use your wrapper class. I am missing some libraries so I cannot tell if everything compiles, but the solution must be close to this

```
template <ESPIChipsets chipset, uint8_t data_pin, uint8_t clock_pin, EOrder rgb_order = RGB>
class LEDState {
private:
  std::unique_ptr<CRGB[]> _leds;
  std::unique_ptr<CRGB[]> _pixels;
  const uint16_t _pixel_count = 0;
  const uint16_t _led_count = 0;
  const uint8_t _mapmode = 0;

public:
  LEDState(const uint16_t pixel_count, const uint8_t mapmode)
    : _pixel_count(pixel_count), _mapmode(mapmode), _led_count(_pixel_count* (_mapmode & 0x0f))
  {
    if (_pixel_count > 0)
    {
      _leds = std::make_unique(new CRGB[_led_count]);
      _pixels = std::make_unique(new CRGB[_pixel_count]);
      FastLED.addLeds<chipset, data_pin, clock_pin, rgb_order>(_leds, _led_count, RGB_ORDER);
    }
  }
  void show() {
  }
};

#define CHIPSET APA102
#define DATA_PIN 23
#define CLOCK_PIN 18
#define COLOR_ORDER GRB 

int main()
{
  const uint16_t pixel_count = 3;
  const uint8_t map_mode = 0;
  LEDState<CHIPSET, DATA_PIN, CLOCK_PIN, COLOR_ORDER> state(pixel_count, map_mode);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried to follow that method (I also did move the constructor to the .h file, because I read somewhere today that that would be necessary in templated classes), but there is still something missing: the compiler complains about "'template<ESPIChipsets CHIPSET, unsigned char DATA_PIN, unsigned char CLOCK_PIN, EOrder COLOR_ORDER> class LEDState' used without template parameters" on `LEDState::show()` in LEDState.cpp.

Comment: Also, I don't know enough about templates to actually extract information from the FastLED library. There's just way too much templating going on in there for me to spot that example that I need.

Comment: You have to move every method to the header when you are using template class. I updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have been the missing information (I don't know where I got the info that I only need to move those methods that are actually using the template parameteres...)

Answer (score 0):

No. What you want to do is not possible.

Your question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861839/can-the-template-parameters-of-a-constructor-be-explicitly-specified), and the same answer applies.

What you want to do would be achieved by a class template. For instance:

```
template<std::size_t N> class foo { /* interface*/ };
```

which you can then instantiate pretty similarly as you wanted:

```
foo<10> bar;
/* Use bar */
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to actually want a class template. Here is how you create one in C++

```
#include <iostream>

template < class T >
class my_class {

    public:
        typedef T type;

        my_class() {
            std::cout << sizeof( type ) << '\n';
        }

};

int main()
{
    auto A = my_class< double >();
    auto B = my_class< float >();
    auto C = my_class< char >();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did find this simple example already, but I don't see how to map it to my problem. I copied the template argument list from `FastLED.addLeds` to my class (resulting in `template<ESPIChipsets CHIPSET, uint8_t DATA_PIN, uint8_t CLOCK_PIN, EOrder COLOR_ORDER> class LEDState`), which then gave me the compiler error "'template<ESPIChipsets CHIPSET, unsigned char DATA_PIN, unsigned char CLOCK_PIN, EOrder COLOR_ORDER> class LEDState' used without template parameters" using the main code above.