# Unlike STL and std::basic_string, why there is no default allocator for std::function

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, std-function, allocator

Unlike STL and `std::basic_string`, there is no default allocator for `std::function`. Why?

There is no default allocator for `std::function` in C++11.
But this article(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/allocators?view=msvc-160) holds the opposite opinion, which says that:

> In C++11 all the Standard Library types and functions that take an allocator type parameter support the minimal allocator interface, including `std::function`, `shared_ptr`, `allocate_shared()`, and `basic_string`.

```
template< class Alloc >
function( std::allocator_arg_t, const Alloc& alloc,
              std::nullptr_t ) noexcept;

template<
    class CharT,
    class Traits = std::char_traits<CharT>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<CharT>
> class basic_string;

template<class T,
class Allocator = std::allocator<T>
> class vector;
```

Comment: Isn't the constructor you're asking about removed in C++17?

Comment: Maybe because the non-allocator versions of these functions would use a "default" allocator? So the only reason to specify it was to override the default?

Comment: @JohnZwinck So, There is no default allocator for `std::function` even in C++11.But this article holds the opposite opinion, which says that:"In C++11 all the Standard Library types and functions that take an allocator type parameter support the minimal allocator interface, including std::function, shared_ptr, allocate_shared(), and basic_string. "

Comment: What is your question then?  We have no idea why Microsoft wrote that.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Miscrosoft says that there is a default allocator for `std::function`, but as far as I can see, there is none.

Comment: Wording didn't say says `std::function` has default allocator in its type, but (pre-C++17), some `std::function` constructors do take template allocator.

Answer (score 2):

In C++11 and later, the most commonly used non-default constructor is this one:

```
template<class F> function(F);
```

I'm going to ignore the others for this discussion because they are less interesting but the same information applies to them.

In C++11 and C++14 it also has this, which was removed in C++20:

```
template<class F, class Alloc> function(std::allocator_arg_t, const Alloc&, F);
```

Your question is why it does not have this instead of the above constructor in C++11 and C++14:

```
template<class F, class Alloc> function(F, const Alloc& = Alloc());
```

The answer is that there is no way to invoke such a constructor using the default argument, because `function(f)` always calls the first constructor, and C++ does not have a way to specify the `Alloc` template parameter.  For more on that limitation of C++, see here: [Can the template parameters of a constructor be explicitly specified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861839/can-the-template-parameters-of-a-constructor-be-explicitly-specified)

Many other types like std::vector are different because their allocator template parameter is on the overall class type, not merely on its constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are aware that allocator support in `std::function` was removed in C++17, so my answer will cover C++11 and C++14, with the [caveat](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/function) that:

> `std::function`'s allocator support was poorly specified and inconsistently implemented. Some implementations [did] not provide overloads (6-10) at all, some provide[d] the overloads but ignore[d] the supplied allocator argument, and some provide[d] the overloads and use[d] the supplied allocator for construction but not when the `std::function` [was] reassigned.

In C++11 and C++14, `std::function` did not have an allocator template parameter because it was not needed. All the members that would *invoke* an allocator also *accepted* an allocator as a function (constructor) template argument; and since `std::function` performs type erasure on the wrapped callable object, also performing type erasure on an allocator would be straightforward.

In the Microsoft documentation (my emphasis):

> In C++11 all the Standard Library types **and functions** that take an allocator type parameter support the minimal allocator interface, including `std::function`, [...]

This is referring to the *constructors* of `std::function` taking allocator arguments (removed in C++17), which are functions taking an allocator; a constructor is a function in this context.

Comment: You see there is default allocator(i.e `std::allocator`) for `std::vector` and `std::basic_string`.But `std::function` does not have a default allocator. Why?

Comment: @John because there's no need for it; the allocator used does not affect the type (since it's erased) and there's no need for the user to know which allocator was used by the constructor not taking `allocator_arg_t`.