# how to print template typename in c++?

Tags: c++, templates, typename

I am writing a wrapper for `boost` `numeric_cast` with the wrapper function something like:

```
#include <boost/numeric/conversion/cast.hpp>
#include <stdexcept>

template <typename Source, typename Target>
Target numeric_cast(Source src)
{
    try
    {
        // calling boost numeric_cast here
    }
    catch(boost::numeric::bad_numeric_cast& e)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("numeric_cast failed, fromType: " + Source + " toType: " + Target);
    }
}
```

I am having this error:

```
error: expected primary-expression before ‘(’ token
  throw std::runtime_error("numeric_cast failed ...
                          ^
```

I think the error is asking to handle `Source` and `Target` in the error message. So is there a way to print `template` `typename`? I am a beginner in c++, so it maybe a silly question...

Comment: what is `Source` and `Target` ? You seem to confuse types with values. What is the expected message for the exception?

Comment: I want it to be something like: `numeric_cast failed, fromType: int, toType: short`

Comment: `Target` must be first since `Source` will be auto deduced.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281818/unmangling-the-result-of-stdtype-infoname

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `typeid(T).name()` to get the raw string of the template parameter:

```
#include <boost/numeric/conversion/cast.hpp>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <typeinfo>

template <typename Source, typename Target>
Target numeric_cast(Source src)
{
    try
    {
        // calling boost numeric_cast here
    }
    catch(boost::numeric::bad_numeric_cast& e)
    {
        throw (std::string("numeric_cast failed, fromType: ") + 
               typeid(Source).name() + " toType: " + typeid(Target).name());
    }
}
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/97Gzf8enM)

Please note that the string literal `"numeric_cast failed, fromType:"` should be `std::string` type to support `'+'` operator.

Comment: Notice that `typeid(T).name()` returns implementation specific value. you might got `"i"` or `"int"` depending of compiler for example.

Comment: Yes, but I think using `typeid` is enough to express type information in this case.

Comment: @Jarod42 yes, it is showing `i` for int, `s` for  short etc for my case(linux), is there a way to handle this?

Comment: @DonBakaD. https://stackoverflow.com/a/20170989/11638718

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should flip template arguments. `Source` can be auto-deduced on other hand `Target` can't. So `Target` must be explicitly provided and should come first in template parameter list, so `Source` could be deduced anyway.

Second problem is that string literals can't be added like that (this comes from C). To build complex strings in C++ use `std::ostringstream`.

To get type name information you can use `typeid`. Since this name is mangled and you already use `boost`, you can demagle that names using `boost` and get nice human readable type name.

Last thing: direct use of `std::runtime_error` is manifestation of lazy developer. It is a good practice to introduce own exception class for such scenarios.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <boost/numeric/conversion/cast.hpp>
#include <boost/core/demangle.hpp>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <stdexcept>

template<typename T>
std::string typeName()
{
    return boost::core::demangle(typeid(T).name());
}

// this is used to bind all exceptions related to local library
class MyLibExceptions : public std::exception
{};

class BadNumericCast : public MyLibExceptions
{
public:
    template<typename Target, typename Source>
    BadNumericCast(Source arg, Target, const char *extra)
    {
        std::ostringstream desc;
        desc << extra << " from type: '" << typeName<Source>()
             << "' with value: " << arg 
             << " to type: '" << typeName<Target>() << '\'';
        mDesc = desc.str();
    }

    const char* what() const noexcept override
    {
        return mDesc.c_str();
    }

private:
    std::string mDesc;
};

template <typename Target, typename Source>
Target numeric_cast(Source arg)
{
    try
    {
        return boost::numeric::converter<Target, Source>::convert(arg);
    }
    catch(boost::numeric::bad_numeric_cast& e)
    {
        throw BadNumericCast{arg, Target{}, e.what()};
    }
}
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/oqGn1Tqh8)

Comment: could we skip the `Target` parameter from the `BadNumericCast` class constructor?

Comment: @DonBaka https://stackoverflow.com/a/2861859/1387438 (second answer has nice workaround)